# Deploying from BIDS to SSRS - Parameters Not Getting Updated

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I'm noticing some strange behaviors when deploying reports from BIDS to SSRS. I have a parameter that has default values, but those default values don't seem to be getting propagated to the Report Server (they are stored in Parameters field in the Catalog table). Yet when I add new parameters I could see the field is changing. It's almost like the deployment tool is ignoring certain parameters. Any thoughts?

If this helps, my RDL looks like this:

```
<ReportParameter Name="INCLUDEDFIRMS">
  <DataType>Integer</DataType>
  <DefaultValue>
    <Values>
      <Value>1</Value>
    </Values>
  </DefaultValue>
  <Prompt>Monkey</Prompt>
  <Hidden>true</Hidden>
  <MultiValue>true</MultiValue>
</ReportParameter>
```

Yet the field in the database after deployment looks like this:

```
<Parameter>      
<Name>INCLUDEDFIRMS</Name>      
<Type>Integer</Type>      
<Nullable>False</Nullable>      
<AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>      
<MultiValue>True</MultiValue>      
<UsedInQuery>True</UsedInQuery>      
<State>MissingValidValue</State>      
<Prompt />      
<DynamicPrompt>False</DynamicPrompt>      
<PromptUser>True</PromptUser>      
<DefaultValues>        
<Value>23</Value>        
<Value>17</Value>      
</DefaultValues>      
<Values>        
<Value>23</Value>        
<Value>17</Value>      
</Values>    
</Parameter>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When overwriting an existing version of a report, certain aspects of the parameters are not updated. This lets you preserve different defaults on the server and helps avoid interruptions to subscriptions.

Try deleting the SSRS version of the report and then re-deploy. This should update the parameters. (But at the expense of losing any existing subscriptions.)